# Why the magic packet can wake_on_lan via lan instead of wan?

Tags: python-3.x, router, wake-on-lan

My simple home internet environment:modem(pppoe) + router + pc.
The modem is a FTTH device which is fiber to the home (FTTH),the delivery of a communications signal over optical fiber.
Setting in BIOS:

```
Advanced--Realtek Lan Controller--enabled
        --Realtek Pxe Option Rom--enabled
Advanced--APM--Power on by PCI-E
```

Setting in router:

```
the ip (192.168.31.52) and mac address are binded together
```

The `start_lan.py` script in my android's qpython3:

```
from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet
send_magic_packet('mac address of my pc')
```

Turn on wifi in my android phone and run `start_lan.py` from android's qpython3,my pc waked on lan via lan,succeeded!
Then i want to wake on lan via wan(external internet environment),there are two status to discuss,one status keep router in the web structure,the other don't.
Status 1:

```
modem(pppoe) + pc
#Remove router
```

Status 2:

```
Keep the web structure as same as wake_on_lan via lan.

Set port forwarding on my router:  

    name  protocol      external port        inner ip address   inner port
    wan   TCP and UDP   30000                192.168.31.52       9
    #the default port for wake on lan is 9.

When request my pc's public ip on the port 30000,it will be forwarded into 192.168.31.52 on the port 9.
```

Both of the two status use almost the same `start_wan.py` script in my android's qpython3:
For status 1:

```
from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet
send_magic_packet('mac address of my pc',ip_address='public ip')
```

For status 2:

```
from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet
send_magic_packet('mac address of my pc',ip_address='public ip',port=30000)
```

Execute the script,my pc can't be waken!Does the FTTH device matter?
How to fix it?

Comment: Did you forward **UDP** port 9? Typical port forwarding is TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Some ISP only open the well-known ports for users,change the port nmuber more small.

Set port forwarding on my router:

```
name  protocol      external port        inner ip address   inner port
wan   TCP and UDP   9                     192.168.31.52       9
```

It is verified that both status can use same code snippet such as below:

```
from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet
send_magic_packet('mac address of my pc',ip_address='public ip',port=9)
```